# Reduce this program to a single line

Tags: bash, shell

I've been trying to implement this on a single line with pipes but I haven't been able to do it. I would appreciate if you could help me out.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

subdir=$(find $1 -type d)  

for ft in $subdir
do
    nFiles=$(find $ft -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
    echo $ft $nFiles
done

exit 0
```

This is what I tried to do but it's not working:

```
find $directori -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f \; | wc -l
```

Comment: What do you mean its not working? What is the `find` command returning then?

Comment: I'd argue that requests to make something a one-liner are not "practical" questions in the sense used in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Code written for practical purposes should value readability, maintainability, and correctness in corner cases; all of these things get compromised when making something a one-liner is considered paramount.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
find "${1}" -type d -exec bash -c 'echo "${1} $(find "${1}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "." | wc -c)"' -- {}  \;
```

Answer (score 1):

the `|` is handle by the shell which redirects the output and input of the involved commands.

It cannot be used directly within the `-exec ...`, because `find` does not propose such feature.

It is possible to use `-print0` to avoid that filenames with special chars break the command.

This sentence can be read from the [echo - open group issue 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) page:

> New applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo.

Give a try to this (**EDIT** see @CharlesDuffy's comment):

```
find "${directori}" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for ft ; do printf "%s " "${ft}" ; find "${ft}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "\n" | wc -l ; done' sh
```

The final `sh` is used to set `$0` see the `man sh`.

Comment: You might consider `_` as a conventional placeholder for the `dummy` value in `$0` -- either that, or `sh` (so error messages read as `sh: yadda yadda yadda`, rather than `dummy: yadda yadda yadda`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : thank you ! good idea, I chose `sh`. Never thought about the error messages... (super remark)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option with pipes, I find it more readable:

```
find $1 -type d | while IFS='' read -r ft; do nFiles=$(find $ft -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l); echo $ft $nFiles; done; exit 0
```

You could also avoid to assign nFiles:

```
find $1 -type d | while IFS='' read -r ft; do echo "$ft $(find $ft -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)"; done; exit 0
```

Comment: If you don't use `-print0 | while IFS='' read -r -d '' ft`, filenames with literal newlines will throw you off. Similarly, there's missing quoting here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.